# Spark Structured Streaming from kafka to save data in Cassandra in Distributed fashion

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'am trying to create a structured Streaming from Kafka into Spark which is a json string. Now want to parse the json into specific column and then save the dataframe to cassandra table with optimum speed. Using Spark 2.4 and cassandra 2.11 (Apache) and Not DSE.

I have tried creating a Direct Stream which gives DStream of case class which I was saving into Cassandra using foreachRDD on DStream but this gets hang after every 6-7 days. So was trying to stream which gives dataframe directly and can be saved to Cassandra.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
          .setMaster("local[3]")
      .setAppName("Fleet Live Data")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "ip")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "20000")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "user")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "pass")
      .set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
      .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
      .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
      .set("spark.cores.max", "9")
      .set("spark.driver.cores", "9")
      .set("spark.speculation", "true")
      .set("spark.locality.wait", "2s")

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Fleet Live Data")
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()
println("Spark Session Config Done")

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
 val topics = Map("livefleet" -> 1)
import spark.implicits._
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

 val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokerIP:port")
  .option("subscribe", "livefleet")
  .load()

val collection = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").map(f => parse(f.toString()).extract[liveevent])

val query = collection.writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/check_point/")
  .format("kafka")
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("keyspace", "trackfleet_db")
  .option("table", "locationinfotemp1")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
  .start()
  query.awaitTermination()
```

Expected is to save the dataframe to cassandra. But getting this error :-

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

Comment: Have you looked at Kafka Connect? This is part of Apache Kafka and is a good way for streaming data from a Kafka topic to a target datastore, such as Cassandra.

Comment: Hint: `.format("kafka").format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")` is not correct

Comment: Did you call `writeStream.start()` at the end of the code?

Comment: @cricket_007 -  I Know its not correct, but I'am actually looking for the solution what should be correct like if I remove .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") this part, then it works but in that case it starts displaying on console and does not save to cassandra.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani - Yes I have written this writeStream.start(), Can you Please scroll on my code in question.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt - Kafka Connect works in distributed Fashion ? Is there any way to check the logs. Basically I wanted to use Spark So looking for solution where Spark can insert my stream into Cassandra.

Comment: Actually, I scrolled and there are only 3 `writeStream.start()` in the page, one for exception and on for you and me. There is no in the code!

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani - **collection.writeStream**
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/check_point/")
  .format("kafka")
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("keyspace", "trackfleet_db")
  .option("table", "locationinfotemp1")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
  **.start()**

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani - Usually what I have learned from examples that we can provide different options between writestream and start() so I was trying to give kafka options and formats

Comment: @Pinnacle yes Kafka Connect can run distributed. If you want to use Spark then fine, I was just checking if you were aware of alternative tools that might fit better.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt - Thanks Robin for the suggestion. I'll try to do POC later but meanwhile can you please help me to get out of this spark thing. any way to write my streaming dataframe to cassandra.

Comment: My point was that you cannot have mutiple formats on one stream. Also, this specific error ("must be executed..."), has been posted multiple times before, so what research have you done to fix it? And I would also suggest not actually writing code at all (i.e use Kafka Connect or a tool like NiFi instead)

Comment: @cricket_007 - ok I understand So, now I tried using only.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") instead of both & got an error -> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka. Also, Yes I checked those multiple posts before posting my question here but none of the posts give solution using read-write stream , either they Suggest to use Dstream and then foreachRDD to save the data into db, which is my case gets hang after running for close to 1 week. & for Kafka Connect, I need Spark only

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, I would say Cassandra is not a Streaming Sink, and I believe you need to use `.write`

```
collection.write
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(...)
    .save()
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

// ...
collection.cassandraFormat(table, keyspace).save()
```

Docs: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#example-using-helper-commands-to-write-datasets

---

But that  may only be for dataframes, for streaming sources, see [this example](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md#writing-to-cassandra-from-a-stream), which uses `.saveToCassandra`

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._

// ...
val wc = stream.flatMap(_.split("\\s+"))
    .map(x => (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .saveToCassandra("streaming_test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count")) 

ssc.start()
```

And if that doesn't work, you do need a ForEachWriter

```
collection.writeStream
  .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {

  override def process(row: Row): Unit = {
    println(s"Processing ${row}")
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}

  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    true
  }
})
.start()
```

---

Also worth mentioning, that Datastax released a Kafka Connector, and Kafka Connect is included with your Kafka installation (assuming 0.10.2) or later. You can find its [announcement here](https://www.datastax.com/2018/12/introducing-the-datastax-apache-kafka-connector)

Comment: For write strategy I got this error - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)

Comment: For cassandraformat - I got "value cassandraFormat is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[class_name]

Comment: I would Like to ask if there is any extra overhead in using ForEachWriter?

Comment: .saveToCassandra - this strategy works fine but I'am nothing but actually saving an RDD into DB which is again much slower then Dataframe or Dataset

Comment: Every `.format` internally uses `ForEachWriter`. Using `.format()` **has overhead** because there is internally serialization happening. And you need to use an RDD at the very base level of Spark because that is what designates a Row within the DataFrame. Regarding the second comment, look at the docs, and check the import statements

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spark 2.4.0, then try using the foreachbatch writer. It uses the batch based writers on the streaming queries.

```
    val query= test.writeStream
       .foreachBatch((batchDF, batchId) =>
        batchDF.write
               .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
               .mode(saveMode)
               .options(Map("keyspace" -> keySpace, "table" -> tableName))
               .save())
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(3000))
      .option("checkpointLocation", /checkpointing")
      .start
   query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: This shows error invalid saveMode - allowed are append , overwrite , etc. Next what should I replace "test.writestream" with like in my case it should be "collection.writestream" or "df.writestream" . If I take "collection.writestream" it gives "Task not serializable" error and for "df.writestream" it gives "Columns not found in table db_name.table_name: key, value, topic, partition, offset, timestamp, timestampType" I just want to save value as per described schema in Question.